# Postgres 13 permission issues with Revoke

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-aurora

I am a relatively new user of Postgres 13.  Let me first tell you, that the Postgres database is hosted on AWS aurora.  I have a user that owns a schema and I have a specific table that this user should only be able to SELECT and INSERT rows to this table and execute TRIGGERS.

I have REVOKED ALL on this table for this user and GRANTED SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER ON TABLE TO USER.  The INSERT, SELECT, and TRIGGER work as expected. However, when I execute a SQL UPDATE on that table it still lets me update a row in that table!  I also forgot to tell you I REVOKED ALL and performed the same GRANTS to rds_superuser on this table since this user is referenced to rds_superuser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Following are the results of `\d`:

```
        Column         |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |        Default
-----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------
 id                    | uuid                     |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 patient_medication_id | bigint                   |           | not null |
 raw_xml               | character varying        |           | not null |
 digital_signature     | character varying        |           | not null |
 create_date           | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 created_by            | character varying        |           |          |
 update_date           | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 updated_by            | character varying        |           |          |
 deleted_at            | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 deleted_by            | character varying        |           |          |
 status                | character varying(1)     |           |          | 'A'::character varying
 message_type          | character varying        |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "rx_cryptographic_signature_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "rx_cryptographic_signature_fk" FOREIGN KEY (patient_medication_id) REFERENCES tryon.patient_medication(id)
Triggers:
    audit_trigger_row AFTER INSERT ON tryon.rx_cryptographic_signature FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION td_audit.if_changed_fn('id', '{}')
    audit_trigger_stm AFTER TRUNCATE ON tryon.rx_cryptographic_signature FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION td_audit.if_changed_fn()    tr_log_delete_attempt BEFORE DELETE ON tryon.rx_cryptographic_signature FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION tryon.fn_log_update_delete_attempt()
    tr_log_update_attempt BEFORE UPDATE ON tryon.rx_cryptographic_signature FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION tryon.fn_log_update_delete_attempt()
```

Following are the results of `\z`:

```
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |           Access privileges           | Column privileges | Policies
--------+----------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+----------
 tryon  | rx_cryptographic_signature | table | TD_Administrator=art/TD_Administrator+|                   |
        |                            |       | td_administrator=art/TD_Administrator+|                   |
        |                            |       | rds_pgaudit=art/TD_Administrator     +|                   |
        |                            |       | rds_superuser=art/TD_Administrator    |                   |
(1 row)
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Hi Laurenz . . . please see above, the requested information has been added.

Comment: Nobody except a superuser or a member of `pg_read_all_data` can update that table. Except if Amazon broke the PostgreSQL permission system.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for all your help, I think I have everything fixed!

Comment: Perhaps you can write an answer to your own question, it might help others.